# Multidimensional array iteration in objective-c

Tags: xcode, multidimensional-array, iteration

I want to learn how I can use for-each statements in 2D `NSMutableArray`. My code is below.  It throws an exception at the 3rd (inner-most) for statement. The exception is:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
```

My code:

```
NSMutableArray* subTryingSet=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self genSetNumbers:arrRandoms withSize:4]];

for (NSMutableArray* oneRow in subTryingSet) {
    for (NSMutableArray* w in oneRow) {
        for (int i=0;i<w.count;i++) {
            NSLog(@"%d", [[w objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a first fast look at your code:

try to change this:

```
    NSLog(@"%d", [[w objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
```

with:

```
   NSLog(@"%i", [[w objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
```

**EDIT**

> "It throws exception at 3th "for statement", so it can't go to slog"

mmm... are you sure that all the objects in oneRow are NSMutableArray?

try to check like this:

```
for (NSMutableArray* oneRow in subTryingSet) {
  if ([oneRow.class isSubclassOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
      for (NSMutableArray* w in oneRow) {
        if ([w.class isSubclassOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            for (int i=0;i<w.count;i++) {
                NSLog(@"%d", [[w objectAtIndex:i] intValue]);
            }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It throws exception at 3th "for statement", so it can't go to nslog.

Comment: ok, you r right meronix. here, w is not an array. i will look why method of genSetNumbers returns "subTryingSet" as one dimensional array. thank you very much. i may ask some questions again about this situation. :)

Comment: actually, the second for must be as "for(NSNumber *w in oneRow)". This was a confusion for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom objective c method to iterate

```
-(void)loopMultArray:(NSArray*)a walk:(void(^)(id node,int index,int zindex))n{

    void(^callback)(id node,int index,int zindex) = Block_copy(n);

    NSMutableArray *l=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:a,nil] autorelease];
    int c=1;
    //This first loop will loop until the count var is stable//
    for(int r=0;r<c;r++){
        //This loop will loop thru the child element list//
        for(int z=0;z<[[l objectAtIndex:r] count];z++){

            callback([[l objectAtIndex:r] objectAtIndex:z],z,r);

            if([[[l objectAtIndex:r] objectAtIndex:z] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
                [l addObject:[[l objectAtIndex:r] objectAtIndex:z]];
                c++;
            }//IF
        }//FOR
    }//FOR

    Block_release(callback);

}
```